# Fabric.js cannot have the background of a canvas transparent

Tags: html, css, fabricjs

I would like to have the canvas (see image) to have a background (around the gabarit) to look like this:

[image]

I have tested to save the canvas with background color set to null and background image set to null, but it's always white.

[image]

The URL of the site is https://linkmx.fr/accueil/307-plaque-downhill-odi-100-perso.html then you have to click on **"Personnalisez"**

Answer (score 0):

You can set the canvas background to transparent like this:

```
canvas.set('backgroundColor', 'transparent').requestRenderAll();
```